# Redirect pico sd card to pc

Tags: pi-pico

How can I redirect an sd card in the pi pico sd adapter to a computer? I want to get the data from the sd card on my pc

Comment: `sd card in the pi pico sd adapter` which board is that? A standard pico doesn't have an SD card adapter / slot.

Comment: you can add an adapter over gpio

Comment: take the card from the pico, insert it into computer ...

Comment: i want to do it through the pico